# X-Men Reading order after 2012?

Tags: marvel, x-men, suggested-order

I have found [this complete guide](https://crushingkrisis.com/crushing-comics-guide-collecting-marvel-comic-books/x-men-reading-order-guide/) for the reading order of X-Men comics and tie-ins but sadly it stops at the publishing year of 2012. Could anyone tell me the reading order for the next events like RessurXion, X-men Gold/Blue/Red, Astonishing X-Men and other possible related stories after AvX.

Comment: Reasonably well reputed source here: https://www.comicbookherald.com/the-complete-x-men-reading-order-guide-modern-marvel-comics-era/#xmen8. I'm aware of various avid readers using their orders, and have used some myself. Pretty good.

Comment: And about Secret Wars... I know that it happens after UMX #180 but should I read the old books Secret Wars I and II or the new Secret Wars 2015?

Comment: I myself am not very knowledgeable. I merely google well and search things. But let me see if I can research anything or find someone.

Comment: Secret Wars (1984) and Secret Wars II have very little in common with Secret Wars (2015), so they're completely optional. Secret Wars (2015) should make sense on its own, though it won't be as cool as it should be if you haven't read Hickman's Avengers and New Avengers runs leading up to it. And if it matters, some of the X-Men were in Secret Wars (1984).

Comment: The timeline is so confusing... I thought the 2015 ones were reprints of the older ones. I am for the moment interested only in X-Men continuity and wanted to know which Secret Wars occur after Professor X is abducted in Uncanny X-Men #180.

Comment: Uncanny X-Men #180 was published in 1984, so it's a pretty safe bet that it's meant to coincide with Secret Wars (1984).

Comment: There are relatively few differences in the primary Marvel universe (previously known as Earth-616) from what's seen before *Secret Wars* and what's seen after it that are *due* to Secret Wars (the most significant change from that is various characters from Marvel's Ultimate Comics line now reside in the primary universe (mostly Miles Morales/Spider-Man, and those tied to him). X-book-wise, the changes are all due to that fact that the post-SW books pick up 8 months later.

Comment: And yes, UXM 180 leads into *Marvel Super-Hero Secret Wars* (the technical title for the original Secret Wars). If it helps: the original SW happened between issues 180 and 181 (but was published over the course of the next year); SW II crossovers were scattered throughout Marvel's comics during the 9 months when that was published; the *Secret War* (note the singular) mini from the early 2000s did not directly tie into anything; and the most recent SW pre-empted your regularly scheduled comics.